# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass with rails params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I have the following code:

```
<% if params %>
    <% puts 'user params are' + params['user'].inspect.to_s %>
           <% if params['user']['type'] == 'Student' %>
              <div class="signup-popup-bg-failure sign-freelancer"><% puts 'opt1stud' %>
          <% else%>
              <div class="signup-popup-bg sign-freelancer"><% puts 'opt2stud'%>
          <% end %>
<% else %>
    <div class="signup-popup-bg sign-freelancer"><% puts 'opt3stud'%>
<% end %>
```

This returns the error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

and the line

```
<% if params['user']['type'] == 'Student' %>
```

is highlighted.

I am trying to change what css class gets displayed depending on the params.

if

```
params['type']['student']
```

exists, I want the class to be:

```
<div class="signup-popup-bg-failure sign-freelancer">
```

If

```
params['type']['Employer']
```

exists, I want the class to be:

```
<div class="signup-popup-bg-failure sign-freelancer">
```

If there are no params, I want the class to be

```
 <div class="signup-popup-bg sign-freelancer">
```

I don't understand why this error exists.  The page says there are no params, so this code should not even be executed.  What's even stranger is that none of the 'puts' statements are getting executed.  This does not make sense either because the if/else logic dictate that one of the puts statements must be getting executed.  Does anyone know how to get this code to work?

Comment: Apparently your `params['user']` are `nil`. What gets printed by line containing `user params are:`?

Comment: Yes, they are nil.  This is printed: "user params arenil"

Comment: So you can't do `nil[]`, that's why you get error.

Comment: Yes [] is a method call, and you are calling on a reference to nil. You should pass the params into a suitable model in your controller, and use an instance of some model entity in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will always have params of some type, at least the action and controller.

Therefore your code is always going to be run (i.e. your `if params` conditional is always going to be true).

In your code you could throw in a `params.inspect` to see what exactly the params hash contains.

Maybe something like this would work for you:

```
<% if params.has_key?(:user) %>
  <% if params['user']['type'] == 'Student' %>
    ... etc ...
  <% else if params['user']['type'] == 'Employer' %>
    ... etc ...
  <% else %>
    ... default ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Although this code could probably be cleaned up using a presenter or decorator like the draper gem or something like on this Railscast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch.

Or even a helper method would be preferable to this kind of logic in the view layer.

Answer (score 3):

fast hack I'm using for such cases is:

```
<% if params.try(:[], 'user').try(:[], 'type') == 'Student' %>
```

instead of

```
<% if params['user']['type'] == 'Student' %>
```

`try()` method is perfectly documented here:
http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try
`[]` is a method sent to `params` hash. By default hash returns `nil` if no key found. That means that your hash doesn't have `'user'` key, and params return nil instead.

You can read about `params` hash here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters

`puts` doesn't function as you would expect in Rails. You should use `logger` object:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#sending-messages

something like:

```
logger.info params.inspect
```

Comment: Is that hack written in whitespace? ;)

Comment: sorry. just pressed tab few times and finished it with enter:)
I really need to sleep...

Comment: What are you expecting `try` to do with an array literal as its argument? And `params` should be (a method retiring) a HashWithIndifferentAccess so symbols vs strings shouldn't matter.

Comment: can't see any 'array literal'. It is just a `[]` method with specific argument.

Comment: thanks for teaching me about params being HashWithIndifferentAccess

Comment: `try([:user])` is calling `try` with an array literal, `params.try(:[], :user)` is the try-ified version of `params[:user]`.